# URL Rewrite from "bare" domain to specific URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, plesk

I need to redirect so when someone types https://mydomain.is to be redirected to https://mydomain.is/issues, I found directive how to do [oposite](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4452322325266-How-to-redirect-specific-URL-to-another-domain-in-Plesk-), but not what I want.
mydomain.is is site hosted in plesk.

Desired output:

```
https://mydomain.is --> https://mydomain.is/issues
```

Found [this guide](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/redirects-in-plesk-windows-shared), but when i click Apply, it shows that web site is about to be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using mod_rewrite? For example insert this at the beginning of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.is$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.is$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/issues
RewriteRule (.*)$ /issues/$1
```